# Difference between classic and xpath selectors

Tags: ruby, xpath, watir

What the difference beetween next sentences?

```
frame.span(:text=>'Patient')
frame.span(:xpath=>".//span[text() = 'Patient']")
```

First sentence works well, but using second with xpath I can't find element on page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Summary**

The difference is in the normalizing of space.

If you set `$DEBUG=true`, you will see that Watir converts `.span(:text=>'Patient')` into the XPath:

```
.//span[normalize-space()='Patient']
```

As a result, there are different results when the text node has leading/trailing whitespace.

**Examples**

For example, in the following HTML, there is no leading/trailing whitespace:

```
<span>Patient</span>
```

As a result, both approaches return the same result:

```
p browser.span(:text=>'Patient').exists?
#=> true
p browser.span(:xpath=>".//span[text() = 'Patient']").exists?
#=> true
```

However, if we add some extra whitespace:

```
<span>Patient </span>
```

We see that the :xpath locator fails since it is looking for the text node to be exactly "Patient" not "Patient ". In contrast the :text locator will ignore the leading/trailing whitespace.

```
p browser.span(:text=>'Patient').exists?
#=> true
p browser.span(:xpath=>".//span[text() = 'Patient']").exists?
#=> false
```